# To disable hiding of cursor on empty lines in Chromebook's Caret?

Tags: cursor, chromebook, usability, caret

The cursor is visible on the top of linenumbers but invisible if get on the empty lines. 
I think the problem is because of

- black background; the default cursor on top of editor is a the horizontal bar (not a pointer), which is difficult to see

This is a pointer:

[image]

How can you change the default cursor to be a pointer on top of empty lines in Chromebook's Caret?

Answer (score 1):

[Caret](https://github.com/thomaswilburn/Caret) is just a browser extension. It uses HTML and CSS and much of its behavior is determined by the browser. However, you can control the cursor display with CSS like this:

1. Open `/main.html` in Caret's source code.
2. Insert at line 6:

   ```
   <style>html{cursor:default!important;}</style>
   ```
3. Reload the extension.

Comment: Yes. I can do that, but I would like to stick to defaults. However, if there would be a config -file where you could add this one, then such an effect can be possible. I hope to get soon a descent editor to Chromebook supported by sufficient development team.